# error procedure in Progress 4gl

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Can someone help me with the procedure below?

It gives me the error on line 95 and I don`t know why?

```
IF (sfa_dz_type = "1" OR sfa_dz_type = "2" /*magda*/ OR sfa_dz_type = "6" OR sfa_dz_type = "7" OR sfa_dz_type = "8" /*magda*/) THEN DO:
   FIND LAST ttqr WHERE ttqr_new = sfa_dz_new NO-ERROR.
   IF AVAILABLE ttqr THEN DO:
   FIND FIRST usrw_wkfl WHERE usrw_domain = global_domain and usrw_key1 = "stocdz" AND usrw_key3 = locfrom AND usrw_charfld[2] = ttqr_old AND usrw_intfld[1] = 1 NO-ERROR.
   IF AVAILABLE usrw_wkfl THEN DO:
        FIND FIRST usrw_wkfl WHERE usrw_domain = global_domain and usrw_key1 = "stocdz" AND usrw_key3 = locto AND usrw_charfld[2] = ttqr_old NO-LOCK NO-ERROR.
        IF AVAILABLE usrw_wkfl THEN DO:
        output to value(lcDir + trim(engcode) + "log.txt") append.
        put today " "
        string(time,"hh:mm:ss")
        "Seria " usrw_charfld[7] " exista deja in locatia " locto SKIP.
       OUTPUT CLOSE.
        ASSIGN
            sfa_dz_trans = YES
            sfa_dz_dbok  = NO.
        END. /*avl usrw_wkfl*/
        ELSE DO:
        FIND FIRST usrw_wkfl WHERE usrw_domain = global_domain and usrw_key1 = "stocdz" AND usrw_key3 = locfrom AND usrw_charfld[2] = ttqr_old AND usrw_intfld[1] = 1 NO-ERROR.
        IF AVAILABLE usrw_wkfl THEN DO:
        ASSIGN
            part      = usrw_key4
            brand     = usrw_charfld[5]
            tip       = usrw_charfld[1].
            DELETE usrw_wkfl.
        END.
        create usrw_wkfl.           usrw_wkfl.usrw_domain = global_domain.
        assign
            usrw_key1 = "stocdz"
            usrw_key2 = locto + ttqr_old + string(TODAY)
            usrw_key3 = locto
            usrw_key4 = part
            usrw_charfld[5] = brand
            usrw_charfld[7] = sfa_dz_new
            usrw_charfld[1] = tip
            usrw_charfld[2] = ttqr_old
            usrw_intfld[1] = 1
            usrw_datefld[1] = TODAY
            usrw_charfld[3] = "mfg"
            usrw_charfld[4] = "dzreadtot.p"
            usrw_charfld[12] = locfrom
            usrw_charfld[14] = TRIM(sfa_dz_eng_code)
            usrw_charfld[15] = "transfer"
            usrw_charfld[13] = "mfg" + "|" + string(today) + "|"
            + string(time, "hh:mm:ss") + "|"
            + "dzreadtot.p".
            usrw_charfld[6] = string(time, "hh:mm:ss").
            output to value(lcDir + trim(engcode) + "log.txt") append.
            put today " "
            string(time,"hh:mm:ss") " "
            "Seria " usrw_charfld[7] " a fost transferata din locatia " locfrom " in locatia " locto SKIP.
            OUTPUT CLOSE.
            ASSIGN
                sfa_dz_trans = YES
                sfa_dz_dbok  = YES.
         /*trasabilitate*/
        create usrw_wkfl.               usrw_wkfl.usrw_domain = global_domain.
        assign
            usrw_key1 = "transfer_dz"
            usrw_key2 = part + string(recid(usrw_wkfl))
            usrw_key3 = locfrom
            usrw_key4 = locto
            usrw_key5 = part
            usrw_key6 = ttqr_old
            usrw_datefld[1] = today
            usrw_intfld[1] = 1
            usrw_charfld[1] = "mfg"
            usrw_charfld[2] = "dzreadtot.p"
            usrw_charfld[3] = string(today) + "_"
                            + string(time, "hh:mm:ss")
                            usrw_charfld[15] = "mutare echip"
            usrw_charfld[6] = string(time, "hh:mm:ss").
        END. /*else do*/
      END. /*avl usrw_wkfl*/
  ELSE DO:
      /*
      FIND FIRST usrw_wkfl WHERE usrw_domain = global_domain and usrw_key1 = "stocdz" AND usrw_key3 = locfrom AND usrw_charfld[2] = sfa_qr_old AND usrw_intfld[1] = 1 NO-ERROR.
      if not available usrw_wkfl then do:
        */
        output to value(lcDir + trim(engcode) + "log.txt") append.
        put today " "
        string(time,"hh:mm:ss") " "
        "Seria " ttqr_new " nu exista in locatia " locfrom
        " deci nu avem ce transfera " SKIP.
        OUTPUT CLOSE.
        ASSIGN
            sfa_dz_trans = YES
            sfa_dz_dbok  = NO.
  END.
 END. /*sfa_qr_code*/
   IF NOT AVAILABLE 
   THEN DO:
       output to value(lcDir + trim(engcode) + "log.txt") append.
            put today " "
            string(time,"hh:mm:ss") " "
            "Seria " sfa_dz_new " nu a fost niciodata inrolata, nu se poate efectua transferul din " locfrom " in locatia " locto SKIP.
        OUTPUT CLOSE.
        ASSIGN
            sfa_dz_trans = YES
            sfa_dz_dbok  = NO.
   END.
```

Comment: If you compile with the option DEBUG-LIST <file> the file will tell what is line 95. Also what error do you get?

Comment: It would certainly help if you showed the actual error message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps; however, based on counting the lines up, I noticed near line 95 of what was pasted is

```
IF NOT AVAILABLE
THEN DO:
```

When I run the following

```
IF NOT AVAILABLE THEN DO:
DISPLAY YES.
END.
```

I get the following compiler messages:

```
** Unable to understand after -- "not". (247)
Missing table name after function. (399)
**  Could not understand line 1. (198)
```

**I can't say if this is the error you are dealing with**, since you didn't post the error message (they usually start with '**' and end with a number in parentheses (9999), like the above compiler messages). However, **you'll still need to add the table name after IF NOT AVAILABLE.**

I'm also not *certain* you pasted the entire program. Compiling with the option DEBUG-LIST as Jensd suggested would include any lines you didn't paste from your program, including the contents of any include files.